# How to remove python-virtualenv RPM using commands that are run from an installing RPM?

Tags: python, rpm, virtualenv, pip

I need to install virtualenv from an RPM.
I do this from the RPM's post-install script, with the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
pip2 install pip --upgrade 
pip2 install virtualenv --upgrade
```

However, the `pip2 install pip` now upgrades PIP to version 10, which throws the following error on the `pip2 install virtualenv` command.

```
Cannot uninstall 'virtualenv'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

A workaround I found is to do an `rpm -e python-virtualenv` prior to executing the above.
However, the `rpm` command cannot be executed from within a running `rpm` installation.

**Any ideas how can I remove python-virtualenv using commands that are run from an RPM?**

Comment: Your link goes to a Stack Overflow help page. I suspect you intended to link to something else. Please edit your question and fix the link.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, but I intended the link to point to [MCVE], so there won't be any _complaints_ that I gave just the bare minimum.

Comment: You have read the relevant [github issues](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247)?

Comment: Yes, naturally.

Comment: What about forcing? `pip2 install virtualenv --upgrade --ignore-installed`

Comment: Thanks, @hoefling, but the issue is no longer relevant (already solved).